# Unique ID when creating Hive table from CSV files

Tags: csv, hadoop, hive

I have a list of CSV files that I want to export as Hive tables but I'm pretty sure that some records are redundant in the CSVs. Each record / row in the CSV are identified by a key and I want to generate the table using that key as the primary key . How will I generate the Hive table such that there are no repeating rows?

Answer (score 0):

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER([partition_by_clause] order_by_clause)
```

returns an ascending sequence of integers, starting with 1.

```
select x, row_number() over(order by x, property) as row_number, property from int_t;
+----+------------+----------+
| x  | row_number | property |
+----+------------+----------+
| 1  | 1          | odd      |
| 1  | 2          | square   |
| 2  | 3          | even     |
| 2  | 4          | prime    |
| 3  | 5          | odd      |
| 3  | 6          | prime    |
| 4  | 7          | even     |
| 4  | 8          | square   |
| 5  | 9          | odd      |
| 5  | 10         | prime    |
| 6  | 11         | even     |
| 6  | 12         | perfect  |
| 7  | 13         | lucky    |
| 7  | 14         | lucky    |
| 7  | 15         | lucky    |
| 7  | 16         | odd      |
| 7  | 17         | prime    |
| 8  | 18         | even     |
| 9  | 19         | odd      |
| 9  | 20         | square   |
| 10 | 21         | even     |
| 10 | 22         | round    |
+----+------------+----------+
```